# How can i send Ethers from My account to sombody else using Smart contract? from truffle frontend

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

I am making Dapp in which a user wants to pay or transfer certain number of Ethers to another Account.
I am using truffle to build the dapp. In which including other features Users has a frontend to transfer Ether from his account to account he provides. i.e

> Input for Number of ethers
>
> Input for account address

Send ethers button

The problem i am facing is how can i transfer ethers from my account to account i have provided with Smart Contract?

> reciever.transfer(amount)

is throwing an gas limit error which is confusing me as i have 100 ethers in my account.

> Sending funds to a contract and have it immediately forward to a given address?

whatever the workaround could be, just that does the job of moving Ethers from one account to the given account. From frontend of my app.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to clarify more what you're trying to accomplish. Sending funds to a contract and have it immediately forward to a given address? Send funds to a contract and then send it in another transaction? Or have a contract withdraw from your wallet and send to another address?

Answer (score 1):

A contract can only send its own funds. It cannot send funds that belong to another address.